# Telerik report showing same data for all columns created dynamically

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have created a telerik report using Visual Studio and set the Datasource from the DataTable. I am creating the columns dynamically at runtime using Telerik.Reporting.TableGroup. Now the problem I am having here is that the report showing the same data for all of the fields and when I debug it is setting different fields for different.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
private void Report4_NeedDataSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt = SalesReport.reportDataTable;
  table1.DataSource = dt;

  Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox textboxGroup;
  Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox textBoxTable;
  table1.ColumnGroups.Clear();
  table1.Body.Columns.Clear();
  table1.Body.Rows.Clear();
  int ColCount = dt.Columns.Count;

  for (int i = 0; i <= ColCount - 1; i++)
  {
    Telerik.Reporting.TableGroup tableGroupColumn = new Telerik.Reporting.TableGroup();
    table1.ColumnGroups.Add(tableGroupColumn);
    textboxGroup = new Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox();
    textboxGroup.Style.BorderColor.Default = Color.Black;
    textboxGroup.Style.BorderStyle.Default = BorderType.Solid;
    textboxGroup.Value = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    textboxGroup.Size = new SizeU(Unit.Inch(1.5), Unit.Inch(0.6));

    tableGroupColumn.ReportItem = textboxGroup;
    textBoxTable = new Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox();
    textBoxTable.Value = "=Fields." + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    textBoxTable.Size = new SizeU(Unit.Inch(1.1), Unit.Inch(0.3));
    table1.Body.SetCellContent(0, i, textBoxTable);
    table1.Items.AddRange(new ReportItemBase[] { textBoxTable, textboxGroup });

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not enough space in a comment unfortunately but here's my advice/suggestion. I'm not certain about your specific error, however in the past I have had issues when re-using variables. You declare your variable outside the `for` statement and it is possible that this is what is causing the problem.

```
private void Report4_NeedDataSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt = SalesReport.reportDataTable;
  table1.DataSource = dt;

  //Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox textboxGroup; 
  //Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox textBoxTable; 
  table1.ColumnGroups.Clear();
  table1.Body.Columns.Clear();
  table1.Body.Rows.Clear();
  int ColCount = dt.Columns.Count;

  for (int i = 0; i <= ColCount - 1; i++)
  {
    Telerik.Reporting.TableGroup tableGroupColumn = new Telerik.Reporting.TableGroup();
    table1.ColumnGroups.Add(tableGroupColumn);

    var textboxGroup = new Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox();
    textboxGroup.Style.BorderColor.Default = Color.Black;
    textboxGroup.Style.BorderStyle.Default = BorderType.Solid;
    textboxGroup.Value = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    textboxGroup.Size = new SizeU(Unit.Inch(1.5), Unit.Inch(0.6));
    tableGroupColumn.ReportItem = textboxGroup;

    var textBoxTable = new Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox();
    textBoxTable.Value = "=Fields." + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
    textBoxTable.Size = new SizeU(Unit.Inch(1.1), Unit.Inch(0.3));
    table1.Body.SetCellContent(0, i, textBoxTable);

    table1.Items.AddRange(new ReportItemBase[] { textBoxTable, textboxGroup });
  }

}
```

Comment: It is changing the Column Header but the data is the same and is of the 1st column

Comment: This is the same issue like me http://www.telerik.com/forums/data-is-being-duplicated---dynamic-report @talegna

Comment: I'm guessing the query is returning the right data, in which case I don't think the binding is working. In my AJAX grids, for example, I've always had to set the data field (can't remember exact word as on mobile ATM) will have a look again and hopefully get back to you if I think I can help further.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest reading the following article. I found this same problem and my solution was to add unique names to the group column, label, and detail  text boxes.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/incorrect-dynamic-table-columns

```
//Added
tableGroupColumn.Name = "group" + *something_uniquegoeshere*;

//Added
textboxGroup.Name = "label" +  *something_uniquegoeshere*;

//Added
textBoxTable.Name = "data" + *something_uniquegoeshere*;
```